# Why Tomcat reloadable=true cause CPU 100%?

Tags: tomcat

When in develop mode, I need the hot reload. I used all kinds of language before, like PHP, Node.js, even Go lang, all languages support hot reload with zero problem. But just in Tomcat, if I set `reloadable=true`, it will cause CPU 100%. In their official document, it says that Catalina will "monitor" class files changes, so that you should not put it as true. But of course I need to set it to true, otherwise how can I redeploy once class files changes? Why the monitoring will cause CPU 100%? Am I setting something wrong? Thank you!

Comment: You can use [VisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/) to check if one thread in particular is responsible of that CPU consumption.

Answer (score 1):

The mechanism Java Tomcat running is different than PHP. For best performance, Java will load all class files into memory, so it will not know if a file on disk changes. To monitor such changes, it need to frequently read disk and compare the checksum of every file, if found difference then load new file into memory, that consume disk I/O huge and cause CPU 100%. For PHP, it's quite simple, PHP will not load every .php files in memory, but load them on demand, that maybe slow for some scenario, but will be perfect to deal with file changes. I believe that's the main difference.

So the conclusion is: NEVER use `reloadable=true` for Tomcat.